# WordPress Permission Issues with LAMP in Debian 10

Tags: wordpress, debian

I created a LAMP server in Debian 10 on Google Compute Engine.
Instead of using **/var/www/site/html** I want to use **/home/user/site/public_html** as a root directory for site.
I added following code in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to enable home directory for sites.

```
<Directory /home/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The permissions for public_html for all sub directories is **775** and for all files is **664**.
Ownership for all files and folders including public_html is **user:www-data**

My site is installed and running but I am unable to install any of plugins because WP is unable to write to the directory. I am getting [this](https://prnt.sc/u5lljn) message when I try to install plugin.

How to Fix this issue?

**EDIT**

However if I set the ownership to **www-data:www-data** then I can install plugins but in this case the user can't use FTP to make any changes to the folder.

Please guide me how can I achieve both.

The solution that comes to my mind is that the **user** gets the sames rights as that of **www-data**. In that case we can assign ownership as **user:user**. So FTP will also work and Plugins will also be able to install.

But I don't know how to achieve this i.e. to assign the rights of www-data to any user?

Answer (score 0):

I have got one solution. If I add the user to www-data group using following command

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data user
```

then user can make changes to the folder once accessed through FTP.

Comment: But a big problem still exists in above answer

I have two users test2 and test8.

I added both of them to www-data group.

The permissions of all files in both users public_html directory is www-data:www-data

Now problem is that if I login to SFTP with test2 credentials I can make changes to test8 files. And this is dangerous.

So I am still looking for a solution that I can give rights to all my files and folders as user:user instead of www-data:www-data in such a way that PHP can also make changes to Folders.

Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution by installing an apache module **mod_ruid2**. For this the following article helped alot.

[https://www.jamroom.net/brian/documentation/guides/1202/configuring-apache-with-mod-ruid2]

But before you may need to install apsx for apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev
```

The apache config file for each site shall include following code in the virtual host

```
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid USER USER
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule itk.c>
            AssignUserID USER USER
    </IfModule>
```